# How to deserialize JSON nested object array to c# object

Tags: c#, json.net

I have been stumped with this and unable to proceed. I am also not very experienced yet so your help would be appreciated.
I am using an API that returns the following data:

```
{"userdata":[{"IdCustomer":"4","IdShop_group":"1","IdShop":"2","IdGender":"1","IdDefault_group":"3","IdLang":"2","Company":null,"Firstname":"John","Lastname":"Doe","Email":"johndoe@email.com","NumpadPIN":"99999999","Birthday":"1991-12-24","Newsletter":"0","Optin":"0","Active":"1","Date_add":"2019-04-09 07:37:29","Date_upd":"2019-07-17 11:38:25"}]}
```

I have the following classes set up by using 'json2csharp'

```
public class Userdata
{
    public string IdCustomer { get; set; }
    public string IdShop_group { get; set; }
    public string IdShop { get; set; }
    public string IdGender { get; set; }
    public string IdDefault_group { get; set; }
    public string IdLang { get; set; }
    public object Company { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string NumpadPIN { get; set; }
    public string Birthday { get; set; }
    public string Newsletter { get; set; }
    public string Optin { get; set; }
    public string Active { get; set; }
    public string Date_add { get; set; }
    public string Date_upd { get; set; }
}

    public class User
{
    public IList<Userdata> userdata { get; set; }
}
```

And here's how I pull the data

```
//changed the url for this question
    var URL = "https://dummyvalue.com";

                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
                    request.RequestUri = new Uri(URL);
                    request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
                    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                    var client = new HttpClient();
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {

                        ApiStatusLabel.Text = "200";

                        HttpContent content = response.Content;
                        var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        // create new object
                        User userObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);

                    }
```

My question is on how do I assign/use the values I have deserialized? I would like to access the values as class object details ex.

```
var name = userObject.Firstname;
var surname = userObject.Lastname;
```

I have read a lot and tried different ways but I must be missing something..

**EDIT** - fixed the class name from RootObject to User

Comment: `User userObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);` should be `User userObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);` Then you'll have the passed object.

Comment: You have to deserialize to `RootObject` or else your C# classes don't match your JSON, right?

Comment: I don't see any definition of `User`.

Comment: @Adriani6, actually it should be `RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);` if anything. Still, the `User` class has not been provided in the question.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel copied the class from a separate test solution, my mistake in posting it to the question

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti Yeah totally, missed the Type declaration my bad. I tend to use `var` in my code mostly for this type of thing so I just assumed stuff - again my bad. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: @Adriani6, yeah, I get you with the `var` thing, I love it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use RootObject

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
foreach(var userObject in response.userdata)
{
    //use here userObject.Firstname;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This answer worked for me but may I ask if there are also other ways to access the object values that are created after deserialization or will it always need to be looped through?

Comment: If you know which object to access then you can use indexer `response.userdata[0].Firstname //replace 0 with the index of object you want to access`